# how to access element in directive?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a html page in which there is a directive(child html) inside as below. I want to do input validation of input1 and input2 in directive(child html) for the button in parent html, but I don't know how I can access the input1 and input2 in child (directive). I would like to know what is the right way to access input1 and input2? Thanks in advance!!

Parent html:

```
<div>

<child></child>
<button name="myButton" ng-disabled="????.myForm.input1.$invalid"><button>

</div>
```

Directive: child

```
<form name="myForm">

<input name="input1" required/>
<input name="input2" required/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Parent controller:

```
vm.myForm = {};
```

Parent Html:

```
<child my-form="vm.myForm"></child>
<button name="myButton" ng-disabled="vm.myForm.input1.$invalid"><button>
```

Child directive:

```
scope: {
myForm: "="
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">

    <input name="input1" required/>
    <input name="input2" required/>

</form>
```

Comment: I would like to know what is vm.myForm = {}; mean? what is vm?

Comment: controllerAs: 'vm'

Answer (score 1):

You can `$emit` event to your parent controller and pass needed data.

**Directive:**

```
$scope.$emit('yourCustomEvent', 'Data to send');
```

And catch the event in you parent controller.

**Parent controller:**

```
$scope.$on('yourCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // will print "Data to send"
});
```

And in your case I advice you to include the button in your directive, it will be much easier to work with it.